# What is a good online source of Brazilian Portuguese language rules?

Tags: discussion

I'm using [nativlang.com](http://www.nativlang.com/) at the moment (example of a rule [there](http://%20http://www.nativlang.com/po/qg_verbs_futuresubjunctive.htm)), but it seems to be rules there are too simplified and lack a lot of details.

What is a better resource online to study Brazilian Portuguese grammar rules?

Comment: Brazilian formal grammar (which is much the same as European and African with the exception of favoring proclisis)?  Or the more distinct differences (especially in spoken) that Brazilian has with respect to other Portugueses?

Comment: Frankly, your better off with books: here are ten books: http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/10-livros-de-portugues-indispensaveis-para-concurseiros/ Online sources are  never as good, I find.

Comment: Definitely this is a question for PL Meta.

Answer (score 3):

I use two sites for that:

1) http://www.infoescola.com/portugues

2) http://portugues.uol.com.br/

I'm sure you can find the most of rules, grammatical staffs and so on on these sites.